Send event from Google Spreadsheet to a Chrome extension
I previously had a Google Spreadsheet where I was able to send an event with parameters to my Google Chrome extension. It was a bit of a hack but the cell in my spreadsheet had something like this -
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#gid=12345678&player=", ENCODEURL(C3), "&team=", D3), "chrome")

Clicking on this link would edit the URL of the current tab, and in my Chrome ext I had something like this in my background.js file -
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.url.match(/google.com\/spreadsheets/g)) {
    console.log(tab.url);
  }
}

This method worked fine for a couple years, but recently Google must've started blocking URL manipulation from within spreadsheets and this broke the message passing hack I had in place. I tried using a content script to place an event listener on the =HYPERLINK() output in the spreadsheet, but Google Spreadsheet outputs the entire DOM onto a canvas so I'm unable to drill down and find the hyperlink element.
Does anyone know of a better workaround for my use case?

You could use Google Apps Script to send the data to a local server and have the Chrome extension listen for those requests and process them.

I initially went the Google Apps Script route, but I didn't want to add running a local server to the process. As far as I know there's no way to pass a message from Google Apps Script to a Chrome ext right?

The hyperlink container will not be loaded until you hover/click on the relevant cell, it is also removed/added when you switch between sheets.
So, using a MutationObserver & the Navigation API should work:
function main(){
    function hyperlinkCallback(e){
        const data = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(e.currentTarget.hash));
        console.log(data);
    }

    const container = document.querySelector('div[id$="static-overlay-container"]');
    const config = {attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

    new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
        const hyperlink = container.querySelector('a#docs-linkbubble-link-text');
        if (!hyperlink) return;

        observer.disconnect();
        hyperlink.addEventListener('click', hyperlinkCallback);

    }).observe(container, config);

}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    main();
    window.navigation.addEventListener('navigatesuccess', main);
})


Thanks for suggesting this solution! It's unfortunate there isn't a more straightforward way to do this, but I can confirm this works.

@RyanGrush well, I don't know if it can get more straightforward than this, even if you use Apps script, there is still the issue of detecting the click. unless you change from using hyperlinks or remove user interaction completely, but that would depend on what your extension does (maybe you can achieve the same thing in apps script?)

Oh it wasn't a critique on your solution! I just wish my old URL manipulation hack still worked or Google didn't obfuscate the DOM as much.
Like I mentioned on Thinkr's comment I preferred this solution over Apps Script because I didn't want to add a server to the mix if I could help it.
